# Is there a way to add product price to Share wishlist email template?

Tags: price, email-templates, wishlist

I'm trying to add the product price to the share wishlist email but I am not having any luck.

Here's what I have tried so far:

> app/design/frontend/enterprise/allbeauty/template/wishlist/email/items.phtml

I've done a var_dump of the `$_product` variable and can see that `price` is available so I have added this code to line 38

```
<p><?php echo $_product = $item->getProduct(['price']) ?></p>
```

This hasn't worked so I would like to know if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: try $item->getProduct()->getData('price')

Comment: And to get it formatted: `<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getProduct()->getData('price')) ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$item->getProduct()->getData('price')
```

For getting proper ways try this

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getProduct()->getPrice()) ?>
```